# SQL database restore failed

Tags: sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL database restore failed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9811/sql-database-restore-failed)

I have a c# application that is connected to my sql server 2005 database, i am working on the application to insert some entries in the database and due to power failure system got down and from that time onwards i am getting this error. I refresh the database, make a copy of it, delete it & try to attach it again and thus the error occurs.

> The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open transactions/users
>   when the database 
>       was shutdown, no checkpoint occurred to the database, or the database was read-only. This  error could occur if the transaction log
>   file was manually deleted or lost due to a hardware  or environment
>   failure.

If i use the log file while attaching the db, i got this error

> The log scan number (1224:41:1) passed to log scan in database 'test' is not valid. This error may indicate data corruption or that the log file (.ldf) does not match the data file (.mdf). If this error occurred during replication, re-create the publication. Otherwise, restore from backup if the problem results in a failure during startup.

Comment: Your transaction log is corrupt. You need to restore from a backup.

Comment: Do you have a recent backup to recover from?  You may need to run DBCC Checkdb to determine the extent of the corruption.  Note, some of these options can cause data loss (REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS, for example).  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064(v=SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you copying the mdf/ldf files with SQL Server running? That will almost never give you a usable copy, unless there are no writes to either file during the entire copy process. Either stop SQL Server or detatch the database before copying the files.

Comment: You should ALWAYS run the built-in `BACKUP` command to make backups of the database.

Comment: Detaching the database and copying the files is perfectly acceptable as long as you don't mind taking the database offline, and ending up with much larger files to back up. You'd rarely do this on a multi-user server, but this is why Express Edition has auto-close enabled by default.

Comment: Except where you have an I/O error and your files don't re-attach again. Always use the `BACKUP` command.

Comment: Backups aren't immune from I/O errors either. If you're concerned with janky hardware, then you need to be doing full and log backups with verification.